# Asp.net core database data displayed more often than existing

Tags: database, linq, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm wondering why my ASP.NET Core MVC Project is listing my data double.

What it should be:

[image: should be]

What it gives me:

[image: gives me]

See the difference?

My Controller (Controller Class - Index()-Method):

```
        [HttpGet()]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string id)
        {
            IQueryable<string> werkeQuery = from m in _context.TestDbSet
                                            orderby m.Id
                                            select m.Id;

            var test = from t in _context.TestDbSet
                       orderby t.Id
                       select t;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                test = (IOrderedQueryable<TestSet>)_context.TestDbSet.Where(x => x.Id == id);
            }

            var filter = new TestSet
            {
                Werke = new SelectList(await werkeQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()),
                Liste = await test.ToListAsync()
            };

            return View(filter);
        }
```

My Model-Class (could there be the error?):

```
`[Table("Test", Schema = "dbo")]
public class TestSet
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Werk")]
    [Column("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mitarbeiter ID")]
    [Column("M_ID")]
    public string M_Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Beginn")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Beginn { get; set; }

    [Column("Ende")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Ende { get; set; }


    [NotMapped]
    public SelectList Werke { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<TestSet> Liste { get; set; }
}`
```

My View (relevant code: displayed list):

```
`@model DienstplanAnzeige.Models.TestSet

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Startseite";
}


<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <select class="custom-select" asp-for="Id" asp-items="@Model.Werke">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Werk auswählen</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Anzeigen" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" />
    </div>
</form>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Liste[0].Id)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Liste[0].M_Id)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Liste[0].Beginn)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Liste[0].Ende)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var item in Model.Liste)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.M_Id)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Beginn)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ende)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>`
```

My Context-Class (named "TestContext"):

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TestSet> TestDbSet { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi @Marco Maier, could you please share your model design and razor view?

Comment: Hi @Rena, I've edited the post. Maybe you can help me. In the meantime I have found out that this error occurs when reading the data. Could it be the model class?

Comment: Hi @Marco Maier, I have tested your code but it works well. Could you please share how do you configure DbContext for TestSet? Besides, you said `I have found out that this error occurs when reading the data`, so which line you get double record?

Comment: Hi @Rena, I have edited the post again - find the context above. Yes, when I was troubleshooting I found out that the `Liste` variable in the controller already is listed like that - which I cannot understand.

Comment: Hi @Marco Maier, did you configure something like:`modelBuilder.Entity<TestSet>()
                .HasKey(t => new { t.Id, t.M_Id });` in `OnModelCreating` method in your DbContext? Because I see your database contains duplicated Id, so it seems Id is not the primary key.

Comment: Hi @Rena, I have added a "hidden" primary key (identity). Now it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, since your **id** property and parameter is in string therefore instead of using **==** comparison operator you should use **Equals(...)** method of string class i.e.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
{
     test = (IOrderedQueryable<TestSet>)_context.TestDbSet.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```